# Wordpress file in appears always after delete

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress site was hacked so I delete all files and reinstall wordpress. But few days ago I found a new file "cause.php" with in a root directory. I look for logs and found some POST queries with random php files, so I made a full scan, deleted all of them again, delete all users and clean wordpress files. I'm also disable all ftp accounts. 
But few hours ago I found file "cause.php" in a root directory again. There is no other files and there is no POST queries in a logs. I deleted it again and few hours ago it appear again. 
I dont understand how it can appear again and again, can someone give me advice ho to find vulnerability?

Comment: Have you followed these steps? https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Comment: This might fit better over at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ - But you need to ensure that your directories have the correct permissions, your .htaccess file is secure, and any plugins / 3rd party files you have on your server are secure.